# How do I enable cancel button with form validation?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, cancel-button

I'm using the `frmvalidator` javascript found [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) for my code.

I had to create a custom validation because I'm validating two input fields with the same id (I'm using an array). The validation is working, the problem now though is when I click the `cancel` button, the validation still takes effect meaning I can't close the `dialog box` unless I fill in all fields.

[image: This error message still appears when I click cancel.]

Here's my code:

```
<form name="UpdateIndustry" action="addIndustry.jsp" method="get">
  <table align="center">                
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${paramValues.industries}">
      <jsp:setProperty property="tableId" name="bean" value="${row}"/>
      <c:set var="ctr" value="${ctr + 1}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="hello" value="${row}"/>
      <tr><th>INDUSTRY NAME</th>
          <td><div id='UpdateIndustry_industryName_errorloc' style="color:red;"></div>
              <input type="text" name="industryName" size=40 value="${bean.thisIndustry.INDUSTRYNAME}"/></td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <input type="hidden" name="finalCount" value="${ctr}"/>
    <tr><td style="text-align:center" colspan="3">
        <input type=submit name="submit" value="Update Industry" onclick="btnUpdate_click()"/>
        <input type=submit name="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="btnCancel_click()"/></td></tr>
  </table>  
</form>
```

and the `script`:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("UpdateIndustry");
    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
    function btnUpdate_click(){
        frmvalidator.setAddnlValidationFunction(FinalValidator); }                  
    function btnCancel_click(){
        frmvalidator.clearAllValidations();
        window.close(); }   
</script>
```

and here's the `FinalValidator` function, where the validation happens.

```
function FinalValidator()
{
   var myForm = document.forms["UpdateIndustry"];
   if (myForm.industryName.length > 0) {
      for(var i=0; i <= myForm.industryName.length; i++)
        {
          if(myForm.industryName[i].value.length == 0)
            {
              sfm_show_error_msg('Please enter industry name.', myForm.industryName[i]);
              return false;
            }
        }
   }
   return true;
}
```

How can I get the `cancel` button to work? Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Comment: " two input fields with the same id" is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#YourButtonID").click(function () {
        error = false;
        $(".span1").remove();
        if ($("#YourTextBoxID").val() == "") {
            $("#YourTextBoxID").after("<span class='span1'>Write Your Error</span>");
            error = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Try this.